# python 3.1 - DictType not part of types module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what I found in my install of Python 3.1 on Windows.

Where can I find other types, specifically DictType and StringTypes?

```
>>> print('\n'.join(dir(types)))
BuiltinFunctionType
BuiltinMethodType
CodeType
FrameType
FunctionType
GeneratorType
GetSetDescriptorType
LambdaType
MemberDescriptorType
MethodType
ModuleType
TracebackType
__builtins__
__doc__
__file__
__name__
__package__
>>>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the doc of the `types` module (http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/types.html),

> This module defines names for some object types that are used by the standard Python interpreter, but not exposed as builtins like `int` or `str` are. ...
>
> Typical use is for `isinstance()` or `issubclass()` checks.

Since the dictionary type can be used with `dict`, there is no need to introduce such a type in this module.

```
>>> isinstance({}, dict)
True
>>> isinstance('', str)
True
>>> isinstance({}, str)
False
>>> isinstance('', dict)
False
```

(The examples on `int` and `str` are outdated too.)

Answer (score 3):

Grepping /usr/lib/python3.1 for 'DictType' shows its only occurrence is in `/usr/lib/python3.1/lib2to3/fixes/fix_types.py`. There, `_TYPE_MAPPING` maps  `DictType` to `dict`.

```
_TYPE_MAPPING = {
        'BooleanType' : 'bool',
        'BufferType' : 'memoryview',
        'ClassType' : 'type',
        'ComplexType' : 'complex',
        'DictType': 'dict',
        'DictionaryType' : 'dict',
        'EllipsisType' : 'type(Ellipsis)',
        #'FileType' : 'io.IOBase',
        'FloatType': 'float',
        'IntType': 'int',
        'ListType': 'list',
        'LongType': 'int',
        'ObjectType' : 'object',
        'NoneType': 'type(None)',
        'NotImplementedType' : 'type(NotImplemented)',
        'SliceType' : 'slice',
        'StringType': 'bytes', # XXX ?
        'StringTypes' : 'str', # XXX ?
        'TupleType': 'tuple',
        'TypeType' : 'type',
        'UnicodeType': 'str',
        'XRangeType' : 'range',
    }
```

So I think in Python3 `DictType` is replaced by `dict`.

Comment: @ubuntu Am actually dealing with a 2.x script conversion. isinstance(x,dict) works for now. Thanks.