# Please ignore this. `types.DictType.__new__(types.DictType, (), {})`

Tags: python

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8424968/) gives this code to construct a new dict.

```
import types
d = types.DictType.__new__(types.DictType, (), {})
```

Which seems to be a Python2 code

```
>>> types.DictType.__new__(types.DictType, (), {})
{}
```

Run this in Python3 produces this error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-b2f9ffc89bc4> in <module>
      1 import types
----> 2 d = types.DictType.__new__(types.DictType, (), {})
      3 d

AttributeError: module 'types' has no attribute 'DictType'
```

What is the equivalent code to `types.DictType.__new__(types.DictType, (), {})` in Python3?

What is the difference between `types.DictType.__new__(types.DictType, (), {})` and just `{}`?

I've already asked the same question to the poster.

Comment: *Don't*? Just use `{}`.

Comment: That post is a) not the accepted answer to the question of how to create a dict and b) doesn't even give that as the preferred solution, just a silly third option. Why on earth did you take it as the actual way to create a dict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`types.DictType` does not exist in python 3, because it didn't need to. We already have `dict`, so it was dropped in python 3.

If you're looking for the equivalent code, it would look like the following:

```
dict.__new__(dict, (), {})
```

Suffice to say, you should never really have to use it. Just use `dict` literal directly.

```
new_dict = {}
#alternatively
new_dict = dict()
```

To quote the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html) of types:

> This module defines utility functions to assist in dynamic creation of
>   new types.
>
> It also defines names for some **object types that are used** by the
>   standard Python interpreter, **but not exposed as builtins** like int or
>   str are.

-emphasis mine

Note that since dict *is* exposed, we shouldn't expect it inside `types` in the first place.

EDIT: Also see a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772049/python-3-1-dicttype-not-part-of-types-module/3772090#3772090)